# Is there a 'JDBC Types Mapped to Database-specific SQL Types' table for JDBC 4.0?

Tags: jdbc

This table is available for the JDBC 3.0 in [section 9.9.7 of the JDBC 3.0 API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html#1053867).

I've downloaded the [JDBC 4.0 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr221/index.html) (jdbc4.0-fr-spec_.pdf), but this table is not documented in this specification. In Appendix B there are some mapping tables, but not with database specific SQL types like as in JDBC 3.0 API reference.

Does anyone know where to find this table for JDBC 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html